# How to set current date and time in table field using zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am having table called users with following fields ,

`is_login(tinyint(1))` and `last_login(datetime)`.

Below is the piece of code to update when user is online using Zend,

```
public function updateLastLoginDetails($id){
            $currentDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $data = array('is_online' => 1,'last_login'=>$currentDateTime);
            $this->_db->update( 'users', $data,'id = '.$id);
}
```

Here i am using `$currentDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` to store current data and time. But it seems not ok with time. 
Kindly suggest me the best way to store current data and time using Zend .
Thanks in Advance,
Dinesh Kumar Manoharan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what's causing your problem, but I find using NOW() to be easier. Also, you should ensure the variable `$id` gets quoted in the update's where condition.

```
public function updateLastLoginDetails($id){
    $data = array('is_online' => 1, 'last_login' => new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'));
    $this->_db->update('users', $data, array('id = ?' => $id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to use `$data` anywhere in your code!

```
public function updateLastLoginDetails($id){
    $currentDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $data = array('is_online' => 1, 'last_login'=>$currentDateTime);
    $this->_db->update('users', $data, 'id = '. (int)$id);
}
```

You might want to consider using a `TIMESTAMP` field in place of a `DATETIME` for `last_login` and have MySQL update it automagically.

Comment: what do you end up being stored in the `last_login` field?

Comment: I want to store like '2011-06-17 18:07:54' in last_login field

Comment: and when you use this code what is stored in the field instead?

Comment: when user logged in the site,I have to update the user table with current data and time with corresponding user.

Comment: why not using SQL function NOW() for the last_login field?

Comment: You say you want to store something like '2011-06-17 18:07:54' in the field. What does the code do at the moment if not that?

Answer (score 0):

Hi am I understanding correctly that the year month and day are being inserted correctly but not the hour minutes and seconds? If that is the case can you please provide use with a describe of the users table. Just execute "DESCRIBE users" in phpMyAdmin.

If that is the case it could be that the field is of type DATE and not DATETIME.

Comment: Thanks,I have last_login as datetime